# Fetch Cluster Metadata from a Connect Worker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Given a connect worker that is part of the cluster, does it expose any way to get **cluster level metadata** from the worker? The worker could die and rejoin. The cluster information should change accordingly.
Something like this

```json
HTTP 1.1 GET 8083/cluster
200 OK
{
   ...,
   "kafka_cluster_id": "CID"
   workers: [
       "worker-id-1": [
          "name": "name-2",
          "addr": "10.10.3.4"
       ],
       "worker-id-2": [
          "name": "name-2",
          "addr": "10.10.3.5"
       ]      
   },
   ...
}
```

I understand that the **cluster metadata can be expensive to compute**, especially if the information is not stored locally (each worker is decoupled from others) and what constitutes a meta is debatable.

I **argue** that whatever useful cluster attributes are cheap to gather, should be a part of the meta. Other technologies do it

- **Storm** exposes a summary API `/v1/topology/summary`
- **Elasticsearch** exposes its state `/_cluster/state`
- **Kafka** connect has a `/` which emits a cluster id and a commit hash. That's it

So, What are the options in Kafka connect to get some cluster level metadata? More specifically, the internal IP addresses of the workers.

---

One way Kafka Connect could provide this is by relaying the messages in the `status.storage.topic`, doing   a deduplication by the latest generation and then presenting the results.

For example, the `status.storage.topics` yield the following, which could be grouped by `generation`

```json
....
{"state":"RUNNING","trace":null,"worker_id":"10.33.3.4:8083","generation":118}
{"state":"RUNNING","trace":null,"worker_id":"10.33.3.5:8083","generation":118}
```

This could then be exposed at an `/_admin` or `/_cluster port`?

Thoughts? Am I missing anything?

Comment: You can hit `/connectors/:name/status` to get the IPs of specific worker tasks. Otherwise, coupling with JMX collection tools would be the next option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Okay, but this is at a task level. And only the workers running the task are exposed which means I need to aggregate unique workers over all tasks. JMX collection seems a bit clunky as well.

Comment: Yeah, there is no built-in thing for this, though, other than fiddling with that status topic, like you pointed out.